# Compare elements of a tuple with a string

Tags: python, tuples

Hi guys i have this tuple and when i print it :

```
for i in range(len(myresult)):
  print(myresult[i])
```

i get this results

```
('https://www.docenti.it',)
('www.feed.com',)
('feeeed.com',)
```

i would like to do somethik like

```
 for i in range(len(myresult)):
      if(myresult[i]=="www.feed.com")
```

But it doesn't work beacause of the  ",)" , i suppose , do you know how can i make it work ?

Comment: Just index on the first and only element of the tuples ? `if(myresult[i][0]=="www.feed.com")`

Answer (score 0):

Its because each element of your tuple is itself a single-element tuple.

You could access that element directly by calling:

```
for i in range(len(myresult)):
    if myresult[i][0]=="www.feed.com":
        # put if-statement code here
```